# this.$axios.get not fetching data

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have defined this method below to fetch json data but I request is not sent. So I tested it whether the URL shows me the data http://localhost:3000/visits.json and this works perfectly fine.

This is how I have defined it.

```
<template>
  <v-form :model='visitor' ref='editVisitorForm'>
   <div class="input-group__input">
    <treeselect v-model="visit_reports"
                        :closeOnSelect="true"
                        :multiple="true"
                        :options="visits"/>
   </div>
  </v-form>
</template>


<script>
 data: function () {
      return {
       visits: [],
       visit_reports: []
      }
},
created: function () {
      this.fetchAttributes();
    },
methods: {
 fetchAttributes() {
   this.fetchVisits();
 },
 fetchVisits() {
   this.$axios.get('/visits.json')
   .then(response => {
     this.visits = response.data;
   });
 }
}
</script>
```

Please help me find the problem.

Comment: When you say the request is not sent, do you mean that it doesn't appear in the Network tab of the developer tools? Do you see any errors in the console? Have you tried putting console logging inside `fetchVisits` to confirm which parts of the code are actually running?

Comment: @skirtle yes you are right the request doesn't appear under the network tab.

Comment: Have you plugged in Axios specially to be able to use it as `this.$axios`?  It would be just `axios(` or `this.axios(` if using `vue-axios` package

Comment: @Dan There was a typo in my code that was causing the problem.